# How to measure request per seconds in python tornado?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I want to know if there is a way to measure my project request per second?
Of course it's possible to log all requests but I thinks It maybe slow down my applications.
My application is a REST API python tornado project.

Comment: For testing your server performance? You can look into the [Apache Bench tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732182/ab-load-testing).

Comment: @xyresnot I think it's for projects running on apache. I want to test REST API

Comment: No. Apache bench tool is a command line program that you run to test any server. Did you even bother to open the link I posted in my comment?